# How to add grant permissions to a group?

Tags: user-management

I have created a group 'programmer' which must have full rights to folder /var/www/. how can i give these permissions to this group and later on i will add users to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using `chmod`.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
chmod g+rwx <directory_name>
```

For more information on the use of `chmod` see [chmod Man Page](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chown -R :programmer /var/www/
sudo chmod g+rwx /var/www/
```